# Accessing Hadoop Counters in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am having a problem accessing Counters from a different Configuration. Is there any way to access Hadoop Counters from different Configurations while implementing map reduce on java, or are the counters Configuration specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counters are at two levels. Job level and task level.

You need to use the configuration and context object if you want to track the job level aggregations.

If you want to count at the task level for example, if you want to count number of times map method is called , you can declare a global variable in Mapper method and increment it when map method is called and write it to context object in the cleanup method.

Comment: i get the first part, but couldn't understand what you mean by the second part (task level).

Comment: Task level is at individual Mapper level or reducer level.

Comment: yeah i got that, but don't you think that would give me the total number of times the mapper has been called, by total i mean, by the complete cluster.

Comment: No , that is job level scenario. You need to use configuration in that scenario